Can you use the beta-binomial distribution instead of MCMC?
So, i have a project to test the hypothesis that a marketing campaign with a new art generates more purchases than the old one, i have 2 samples of data, one using the standart ad and one using the new ad. So we have the total number of impressions and the number of purchases. We can estimate this as a Binomial(impressions,purchases/impressions). So, if we say that:
$$
\begin{align}
&X_{c} \sim Binomal(I_{c},\theta_{c})\\
&X_{t} \sim Binomial(I_{t},\theta_{t})
\end{align}
$$
and we use a $\theta \sim Beta(1,1)$ as a prior we can get the respective posterior for the test and the control. So, my question is, can i use the beta-binomial distribution as a analytic way to do the hypothesis test? Or do I have to use a MonteCarlo Markov Chain simulation and do it the usual way?
My reasoning was that, given the data, we can calculate the probability of the number of puchases $\tilde{x}$ as
$$
P(\tilde{x}=x \ |X_{t},\theta'_{t})\sim \text{Beta-Bin}(I_t,1+x_t,1+I_t-x_t)
$$
with $\theta'_t$ being the posterior of $f(X_t \ | \ \theta_t)$ and $x_t$ the number of purchases that the test advertisement had. So i could use this to calculate the BayesFactor
$$
BF_{10}=\frac{P(\tilde{x}\geq x_t \ | X_t ,\theta_t')}{P(\tilde{x}\geq x_t \ | X_c ,\theta_c')}
$$
instead of using the usual MCMC simulation and comparing the results

Might be a better fit for the Statistics stack.

@Aruralreader Thanks for the tip. Posted it there!
